# Register a Broadcastreceiver in a Class

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a Bluetooth Discovery in Android. I want to put this action in a different class than the MainActivity of my app. I tried to extend my new class with AppCompatActivity but it doesn't work. I can't register the receiver. Here is a small part of the code.

```
public class BTManager extends AppCompatActivity {
     public void scanDevices()
     {
      IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
      IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
      registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
      registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
      myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
            {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                DiscoveredDeviceList.add(device);

            }
            if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

    }
  };
}
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work*. What happens ?

Comment: the app crashes when executes registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);

Comment: with this code
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check whether mReceiver is null or not in registerReceiver ?

Comment: whare are you calling  scanDevices() ?

Comment: It seems that mReceiver is not null :(

Comment: I call scanDevices() in: 

    'public BTManager(){
        Initialize_Bluetooth();
        scanDevices();
    }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> call `scanDevices()` in: `public BTManager() {
>   Initialize_Bluetooth(); scanDevices(); }`

you can't use the default `Constructor` for this purpose. You need a valid initialzied `Context` object to call `registerReceiver`. Get rid of `public BTManager()` and move

```
 Initialize_Bluetooth(); 
 scanDevices();
```

into `onCreate`

Comment: How can I can call the class from the MainActivity?

Comment: moving that code in MainActivity is the simplest way

Comment: If I need to put this code in a different class? How can I do that?

Comment: copy past it into MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BTManager extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
///// your code
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
  BluetoothDevice device =       intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            DiscoveredDeviceList.add(device);
        }
        if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){

        }
   }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
};

}
```